# pointer assignments not holding through multiple functions c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, scheduler

I'm writing a small program to simulate schedulers inside an OS and during execution I am noticing that when I assign a new value to the head pointer of my linked list that this does not carry over into the next function. Its almost as if I don't even have it written.

```
//insert at head of Event queue
if(ecursor == ehead){
    cout << "insert at head" << endl;
    eve->prev =  NULL;
    eve->next = ecursor;
    ecursor->prev = eve;
    ehead = eve;
    ecursor = eve;
}
```

Ive double checked the insert login to make sure im not missing anything, and it works for other insertions. At some point it just never assigns the head pointer correctly.

After an insert the head pointer is read into the main body of the program which then displays the time at which an event will take place (presumably the event in which we just made the head equal to)

event type: 2

check for events in queue

ecount: 1

check event order

eve->time: 0.0667091

ecursor->time: 0.0108831

insert after tail

scheduling arrival: 1

event type: 1

check for events in queue

ecount: 1

check event order

eve->time: 0.015281

ecursor->time: 0.0667091

insert at head

clock: 0.0667091

type 1: **arrival**

type 2: **departure**

As you can see the last insertion was inserted at the head and the new head time should be the inserted event time but the clock does not show that change.

here is some of the program for reference

```
void insert_event(struct event* eve)
{
ecursor = ehead;

cout << "event type: " << eve->type << endl;

cout << "check for no events in queue" << endl;

cout << "ecount: " << ecount << endl;

if(ecount == 0){

    ehead = eve;

    eve->next = NULL;

    eve->prev = NULL;

    etail = ehead;
}


//if newEvent is preceded by other events/event queue not empty
else{
    cout << "check event order" << endl;
    //insert new arrival into Event queue
    do{
        cout << "eve->time: " << eve->time << endl;
        cout << "ecursor->time: " << ecursor->time << endl;
        //new arrival earlier than event cursor points to 
        if(ecursor->time >= eve->time){

            //insert at head of Event queue
            if(ecursor == ehead){
                cout << "insert at head" << endl;
                eve->prev =  NULL;
                eve->next = ecursor;
                ecursor->prev = eve;
                ehead = eve;
                ecursor = eve;
            }

            //insert inside of Event queue
            else{
                cout << "insert inside " << endl;
                ecursor->prev->next = eve;
                eve->next = ecursor;
                eve->prev = ecursor->prev; 
                ecursor->prev = eve;
            }
            break;
        }

        //new arrival after final event in Event queue
        //insert at tail of Event queue
        else if(ecursor == etail && (ecursor->time < eve->time)){
            cout << "insert after tail" << endl;
            ecursor->next = eve;
            eve->prev = ecursor;
            etail = eve;
            break;
        }

        ecursor = ecursor->next;
    }while(ecursor != NULL);

    //reset ecursor to head of Event queue
    ecursor = ehead;


//increment Event queue count
ecount++;
}


int process_event_ARR(struct event* eve){

cout << "processing arrival: " << pacount << endl; 
//generate new process
struct process* proc = new process;


//process time starts now
proc->start = simclock;

//generate service time for process
proc->serTime = genexp(1/Ts);

//if no processes to service, service arrival instantly
//add departure event
if(!server_busy){

    phead = proc;
    schedule_event_DEP(proc);
    server_busy = true;

    //set CPU to proc
    inCPU = proc;
}

//behavior for process queueing
else{

    //Non Premptive
    if(sType == 1 || sType == 3)
        //process to ready queue
        phead->next = proc;
        phead = proc;
    }
}

//remove arrival from Event queue
remove_event(eve);
eve = NULL;

//schedule new Arrival Event
schedule_event_ARR();

//increment process count
pcount++;
pacount++;
}

int process_event_DEP(struct event* eve){

pcursor = phead;
cout << "processing dep: " << depcount << endl;
//process completed process
eve->link->finish = simclock;

cout << " if no ready queue release cpu" << endl;
if(pcount == 0)
    server_busy = false;

else{
    cout << "creating temp process" << endl;
    struct process* temp = new process;

    cout << "assigning temp process cursor time" << endl;
    temp->start = pcursor->start;

    cout << "schedule next process" << endl;
    switch(sType){
        case 1:     //FCFS
                    do
                        if(pcursor->start < temp->start)
                            temp = pcursor;

                        pcursor = pcursor->next;
                    while(pcursor != NULL);

                    schedule_event_DEP(temp);
                    inCPU = temp;
                    break;
        default:
                    //error
                    break;
    };
};

//remove event from Event queue/process from ready queue
remove_event(eve);
eve = NULL;

//incremement departure count
//decrement process/event count
dcount++;   
pcount--;
ecount--;
}


int run_sim(){

struct event* eve = new event;
while(!(dcount > 10000)){

    eve = ehead;
    simclock = eve->time;
    cout << "clock: " << simclock << endl;
    switch (eve->type){

        case ARR:
            process_event_ARR(eve);
            break;
        case DEP:
            process_event_DEP(eve);
            break;
        case Qtum:
            process_event_tslice(eve);
            break;
        default:
            //error
            break;

    }
    ehead = eve->next;
    free(eve);
    eve = NULL;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry I took some stuff out

Comment: Looks like you might be missing some `{` and `}`? Please check your indentation (be consistent) and do consider removing extra blank lines (to reduce our need to scroll to see everything).

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? There's `std::list` for instance.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl I know this but our professor told us we were not allowed to use it

Comment: Aside. Your program has UB, you can't `free` what you `new`ed, you must `delete` it.

Comment: Your second code block still misses a lot of braces. Fixing this is a first step towards a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. You wont receive much help without that.

Comment: @n.m. - would that lend to pointers not retaining their assignments?

Comment: Theotetically it can lead to anything.

Comment: well ive changed all the `free` statements to `delete` statements, but im still getting the same behavior

Comment: @BKreger people will only help you if you show some incentive, if you help us help you. Reading the second code block hurts, bad indentation, too much code (keep it simple), not enough code (no includes, no definiton of `event`). Follow [this guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and change your question accordingly then people might help you.